# Cost of font-family vs font-weight

Tags: css, fonts

I've inherited a code project wherein the fonts are not set up in the most sensible way. The site uses a few weights of the Proxima Nova font.

Instead of binding these font files to the same font family (i.e. `font-family: "Proxima Nova"`), a new `font-family` is created for each weight of the Proxima Nova font.

In practice, what this means is that in order to change the font weight, you write `font-family: "Proxima Nova Bold"` instead of `font-weight: 700`.

I am curious to know if this has consequences other than the obvious legibility problems. The more technical the answer, the better.

EDIT:

Here is an example to illustrate what my preferred method is, in case there's something wrong with how I do things:

```
@font-face {
   font-family: 'Ubuntu';
      src: url('Ubuntu-RI-webfont.eot');
      src: url('Ubuntu-RI-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
           url('Ubuntu-RI-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
           url('Ubuntu-RI-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
           url('Ubuntu-RI-webfont.svg#UbuntuItalic') format('svg');
   font-weight: normal;
   font-style: italic;
}

@font-face {
   font-family: 'Ubuntu';
      src: url('Ubuntu-B-webfont.eot');
      src: url('Ubuntu-B-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
           url('Ubuntu-B-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
           url('Ubuntu-B-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
           url('Ubuntu-B-webfont.svg#UbuntuBold') format('svg');
   font-weight: 700;
   font-style: normal;
}
```

Another example: [@font-face: Only using one font-family with different font-weights?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8107170/font-face-only-using-one-font-family-with-different-font-weights?rq=1)

Comment: You are right. Abusing font-family names to store styles lead to redundant css code since extra css rules are needed to counter style the default browser style behaviour and define the desired (eg with strong and heading tags). If the counter styling goes wrong (likely) you end up with faux styles. A faux style is when the browser can't find the correct style and calculates the style based on the available font. Letter designers and typographers nightmare! Also pretty stupid since the needed font style is probably loaded only under the wrong name.

Comment: More of this! So this sounds like it fits in with this code-sharing problem (compounded with computed "faux" font weights). Would there be any other drawbacks to abusing font-family?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer: no.

The properties you specify in a `@font-face` rule are used to resolve "the `font-...` values tuple" to "the actual font resource on the network indicated by `src`", so whether you declare your font as:

```
@font-face {
  /* identifying font-... values: 1 */
  font-family: SillyBoldItalicSmallcaps;

  /* font resource to use when values match: */
  src: url(./font-bold-italic-SC.woff) format("WOFF");
}
```

and then resolve it with some document CSS using:

```
.rulename {
  /* values to use to find a specific font resource: 1 */
  font-family: SillyBoldItalicSmallcaps;
}
```

(where the tuple `{font-family}` is matched against the declared tuple) or whether you declare your font as:

```
@font-face {
  /* identifying font-... values: 4 */
  font-family: MyFont;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-style: italic;
  font-variant: smallcaps;

  /* font resource to use when values match: */
  src: url(./font-bold-italic-SC.woff) format("WOFF");
}
```

and then resolve it with some document CSS using:

```
.rulename {
  /* values to use to find a specific font resource: 4 */
  font-family: MyFont;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-style: italic;
  font-variant: smallcaps;
}
```

(where the tuple `{font-family,font-weight,font-style,font-variant}` is matched against the declared tuple) there is no difference in the actual resource *found* by the CSS engine based on the `font-...` values you provided. Both end up finding the `./font-bold-italic-sc.WOFF` font for styling the text: the core mechanic is the same in both cases, in that we "resolve a `font-...` values tuple to the declared resource that matches that values tuple". The important thing to note is that in both cases the tuples are *unique*. In the first case because the `font-family` is a uniquely identifying string, in the second case because while the `font-family` may no longer be uniquely identifying, the additional property values yield a unique combination that can resolve to a single font resource.

The only real *difference* is that the latter makes life considerably easier when it comes to development and maintenance (the end result is identical as far as the consuming client is concerned). And ease translates directly into improved efficient, better code, lower cost, and a whole slew of things that all translate into "we should be doing it this way".

Comment: Awesome answer! For some reason, I had this idea that each CSS property was almost like a function call and that some functions are more efficient than others. But thinking of it as a tuple makes a lot more sense overall. If you've got any recommended reading material about how rendering engines work in general, id be happy to read it.

Comment: Not really. Google finds http://taligarsiel.com/Projects/howbrowserswork1.htm which seems a decent place to start, but as far as I'm aware no one's written authoritative "this is how it works" docs - for firefox, webkit, etc. it mostly ends up being "read the code" or find the authors of said code and see if they blog =)

Answer (score 0):

It is **often** a result of the actual font file encoding and not related to any usage. Some font vendors *do not* package their fonts into one nice, easy family. But instead the foundry itself splits each weight into a new file. (I dislike this, but it's not really that uncommon.)

I believe that Proxima Nova is one such font -- where each weight is a separate file and not part of one "family" file.

Comment: Right. But you can still bind those files to the same `font-family` value. But as far as the encoding issue, are you referring to the file format or something else?

Comment: The file format... if each weight is a separate .otf file.. then it's often not a concern to bind them all to the same CSS declaration. Kind of preference of workflow... either declare the weight when needed or name the family when needed. Also.. many just copy/pasting code form Googlefonts won't bother altering it..and google splits the weights.

Comment: I've added an example of my preferred method. I was thinking there might be some rendering overhead cost associated with `font-family` as opposed to `font-weight`. Similar to how `top` and `left` are more expensive routines during the rendering process.

It might be an imaginary performance difference, but I figured it was worth asking.

Comment: For instance, to force GPU acceleration, you use `transform`, `opacity` or `filter` to force the browser to separate an element into another compositing layer, thus improving frame rate through parallelism. I'm really trying to get a look under the hood here but I'm not sure where to look for information.