# Beginner Question: How to use different font weights for the same font in the same stylesheet?

Tags: css, fonts, font-face

I have added the font face Acumin Pro Condensed twice, both with different font-weights; 400 and 700.

I have tried to apply the font with both seperate weights, 400 on a h3 tag and 700 on a h2 tag, however only the 700 font weight is being applied.

```
@font-face {
font-family: 'Acumin Pro Condensed';
src: url('../fonts/Acumin\ Pro\ Condensed.woff2') format('woff2'),
    url('../fonts/Acumin\ Pro\ Condensed.woff') format('woff'),
    url('../fonts/Acumin\ Pro\ Condensed.ttf') format('truetype');
font-weight: 700;
font-style: normal;
} 

@font-face {
font-family: 'Acumin Pro Condensed';
src: url('../fonts/Acumin\ Pro\ Condensed.woff2') format('woff2'),
    url('../fonts/Acumin\ Pro\ Condensed.woff') format('woff'),
    url('../fonts/Acumin\ Pro\ Condensed.ttf') format('truetype');
font-weight: 400;
font-style: normal;
}

h3 {
font-size: 1em;
color: white;
font-family: 'Acumin Pro Condensed';
font-weight: 400;
text-transform: uppercase;
}

h2 {
font-size: 1.25em;
color: white;
font-family: 'Acumin Pro Condensed';
font-weight: 700;
}
```

I have tried changing the name of the font-family to something different but that doesn't seem to work either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you're defining the same font for both. ([See this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40919389/cost-of-font-family-vs-font-weight))

In your `font-family` bindings, you're saying:

A font-family called `Acumin Pro Condensed` with `font-weight: 700` is here:

```css
src: url('../fonts/Acumin\ Pro\ Condensed.woff2') format('woff2'),
    url('../fonts/Acumin\ Pro\ Condensed.woff') format('woff'),
    url('../fonts/Acumin\ Pro\ Condensed.ttf') format('truetype')
```

Then you're saying the same thing for a weight of 400. When you specify a weight in a font-family binding, you're identifying it so you can use it later, not changing it's weight.

If you want to have a bolder or lighter version of `Acumin Pro Condensed`you would need to find a different `src` for it. You haven't actually added both 700 and 400 weights, you've added the same font twice and said use the same thing whether you ask for 700 or 400.

The great thing is, **you got it to work as it's supposed to**, you just didn't get the ***result*** you wanted. So just find that other font (heavier or lighter), switch the source file address to match and you'll be good to go!

Comment: Thank you very much @Joseph for the help. I understand now that the font-weight value I've added in the src is just to tie the src with when I specify a specific font weight elsewhere in the stylesheet. 
So you're saying that I need to find a light version of the font in question and add it in its own src declaration, e.g. something like Acumin Pro Condensed Thin.
The confusion I had was I that the website I am trying to clone has a h3 and h2 tag which both seem to use Acumin Pro Condensed (based on my limited inspection knowledge), the only difference between them seems to be font weight.

Comment: Just done some more research and realised that the font-weight: 400 example I am looking for must be Acumin Pro Condensed Medium which is Creative Cloud locked, as the default Acumin Pro Condensed appears to be the only free to download version.